# How to get a date value from a DatePicker in React

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using a DatePicker from Antd for React to get a specific date value. I catch the value inside the onChange function but i need that value to export to another component. I tried with a state value but this didn't work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';

class DeliveriesDatePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      day : ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    function onChange(date, dateString) {
      this.setState( { day: dateString } );
      console.log(date, dateString);
    }
    date = this.state.day
    return (
      <div className="Calendario">
        <DatePicker onChange={onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DeliveriesDatePicker
export let date;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

use `onChange={(date, dateString) => this.onChange(date, dateString)}` on DatePicker. Here is the complete example

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {DatePicker} from 'antd';

class DeliveriesDatePicker extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            day: ''
        };
    }
    function onChange(date, dateString) {
        this.setState({day: dateString});
        console.log(date, dateString);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="Calendario">
                <DatePicker onChange={(date, dateString) => this.onChange(date, dateString)}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DeliveriesDatePicker
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply setState inside the render.you need to change you code like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';



class DeliveriesDatePicker extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  day : ''
};
}




function onChange(date, dateString) {
  this.setState( { day: dateString } );
  console.log(date, dateString);
}



 render() {

return (
  <div className="Calendario">
    <DatePicker onChange={onChange} />
  </div>
);
```

}
}

```
export default DeliveriesDatePicker
export let date;
```